# What is use of complex and real part graphs of cubic and higher polynomials with only complex roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

So I was fiddling with graphs and then it hit me what would a cubic polynomial with only complex roots look like ,i.e., no root which is purely real. I gave such an equation to Wolfram alpha which was

$$f(x) = (x-i)(x-2i)(x-3i)$$

My hypothesis was that the graph wouldn't exist in Cartesian system and only roots in complex plane would be shown. But Wolfram alpha expanded the expression and put the factored terms without i on one side and with $i$ on the other. I was able to understand that it was showing me the graphs of real and complex parts on the Cartesian plane but I was not able to understand its utility. Like what is its purpose when the roots would still remain the same. Moreover, the output of real and imaginary parts was same even for $4$ degree and higher polynomials when to my understanding such graphs should be able to be completely above the x-axis for even powers of $x$. Can someone explain to me what are their utilities. Also I noticed that both complex and real parts were equations of the form where the powers were even numbers with difference of $2$. Such as,

$$ax⁶ + bx⁴ + cx² + d$$

Is this something that happens often or is it just the bias of my polynomial.

Edit:

Links for the outputs:

Link 1: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x-i%29%28x-2i%29%28x-3i%29

This is the case of cubic polynomial where the roots are completely imaginary and there has been factorisation done in a column assuming x as real and then two graphs have been plotted.

Link 2:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x-i%29%28x-2i%29%28x%2B3i%29%28x-4i%29

Similar result was observed for quartic and upper polynomials.

Also for the graph I realised I had given it the prompt of (x-i)(x+i) which resolved into x²+1 and as such a graph was possible for it. So I got the answer for that part.

Comment: Please insert screenshots from and/or links to the WA pages you are looking at, since it's not clear what you mean by "*Wolfram alpha expanded the expression and put the factored terms without i on one side and with i on the other*" or "*such graphs should be able to be completely above the x-axis*".

Comment: I have inserted the links.

Comment: This sounds more like a question about the Wolfram program than about math in general.

Comment: I believed that since the Wolfram program was doing it, it must have some mathematical significance. Is it simply something that the program does and doesn't hold any mathematical meaning?

Comment: @Poke_Programmer Sometimes the behaviors of $\operatorname{Re}(f(x))$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f(x))$ are of interest. That may not always be the case, but if you just type-in a polynomial WA can't guess what's of interest to you.

Comment: That is just what I wanted to know. What is their significance, can you please elaborate with an example on how they may be of interest and what purpose they serve

Comment: @Poke_Programmer All the same reasons why the real and imaginary parts of a complex number $z=a+ib$ are used and useful apply to complex functions as well. If $z$ depends on a real parameter, or changes with time, then $z(t)=a(t) + i b(t)$ is a complex function of a real variable. The real and imaginary parts functions $a(t), b(t)$ may be of interest for $z(t)$ for the same reasons why the values $a,b$ may be of interest for a fixed $z$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand.